# Adding user groups to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to make an issue list in excel. People can input a few cells, which sends an insert query to Access ( this works fine so far ). I would like to add user groups however, and since I'm using Access 2013, I noticed that user groups is no longer accessible in Access.

Is there a way to add user identification to excel ? I would prefer to identify users with their windows login. I've though about bypassing all of this by making different password protected sheets in the excel file, based on user access. I would try to identify which user group is currently working by checking which sheet is accessible ( No idea if this is actually possible ).

I am fairly new to Access / Excel / vba and am trying to get the hang of it

As last option I would look into making Access just a front-end, and managing my DB in MySQL and adding user access there.

Answer (score 0):

To get the username in windows you can use:

```
usr = split(Environ("USERPROFILE"), "/")
```

The last index of the array usr should be the windows username.

Environ function returns the users folder so spliting it on "/" and the last index will be username

Not a complete answer to your question but maybe a start?

Comment: This certainly gives me a great start. Since the usernames are fixed and only accessible with their windows password, I could work from here. Thanks a lot!